# Recargar pagina con Vue y API

Tags: vue.js, api, axios, async-await

estoy haciendo una pagina dinamica con Vue, que recibe datos de una API y las muestra en una tabla, todo funciona bien en su primer intento, pero al recargar la pagina o cambiar de ruta, dejo de recibir los datos.

Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Aqui os dejo mi codigo:

```
<script>

    /*import API from '../api';*/
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import VSwitch from 'v-switch-case';

    Vue.use(VSwitch)

export default {
    name: 'Details',
    data(){
        return{
            details: []
        }
    },
    methods:{
        async getDetails(){
            const url = 'https://localhost:44391/Plants/' + this.$route.params.id;
            const r = await fetch(url);
            const details = await r.json();
            this.details = details;
        }
    },
    async mounted(){
        await this.getDetails();
    },
};

</script>
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: la consola tiene algun error? los pedidos van por la pestaña red?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!